# Cannot use async/await on MongoDB Model, even though it returns Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a function which gets a user inventory, and then each of its element's `price` property with the Price gotten from a `Price Collection`.

Here it is (not the whole functon, but I'm getting the error here):

```
async function updateUserInventory(inventory, userDetails, socket) {
    let newArray = await inv.map(item => {
        let price = await Price.findOne({ market_hash_name: item.market_hash_name });
        return {
            price: price.price
        }
        logger.debug(JSON.stringify(item, null, 2));
    });

    socket.emit('user inv', { items: newArray });
```

Now as per the Mongo Docs, you may call Price.findOne with a callback, but you also can call it with a promise (`.then()`). Which means you SHOULD be able to also call it with `await` since it returns a promise. But alas, I'm getting an error which is this:

```
D:\code\some-api\api\helpers\priceUpdater.js:129
        let price = await Price.findOne({ market_hash_name: item.market_hash_name });
                          ^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:607:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
```

It works without the `await` keyword, but I cannot use it like that because then I'll have problems with asynchronicity.

Maybe I am not using async/await properly. Any help?

Comment: what version of node do you have?

Comment: D:\code\some-api>node -v
v8.9.4

Comment: `await` can only be used inside an `async` function, which your `map` callback is not.

Comment: Looks like you are using a Mongoose model, right?

Comment: @georg I thought if the wrapper function was `async` you can call `await` on any level in it. Is this not the case?

Comment: @chridam Yes, mistake, Mongoose model.

Comment: `Price.findOne({ market_hash_name: item.market_hash_name }).exec();`  try this,

Comment: apparently not. The closest function has to be `async`. Feels somehow silly, but that's how it's implemented.

Comment: @RahulSharma tried it, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @georg That is indeed silly. Thanks for the information anyways. Solves my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that encounters the same problem (using `await` inside a `.map` or any JS array iterator function), I solved it by calling `Promise.all` on the `.map` and then `async` on the element being iterated. Thanks to @georg for the pointer.

```
async function updateUserInventory(inventory, userDetails, socket) {
    let newArray = await Promise.all(inv.map(async (item) => {
        let price = await Price.findOne({ market_hash_name: item.market_hash_name });
        return {
            price: price.price
        }
        logger.debug(JSON.stringify(item, null, 2));
    }));

    socket.emit('user inv', { items: newArray });
```

Comment: Also you can iterate using for of

Comment: Yes, it was just an async/await usage problem. In this related question you have more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop/